# UIView set tint color

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating a view like a tab bar. For that I am setting tintColor:

```
UIView *bottomTab = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT-yVal-bottomBarButtonHeight,SCREEN_WIDTH,75)];
//bottomTab.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
bottomTab.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:bottomTab];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bottomTab];
```

But I am not able to see the view. However when I uncomment the background color code line, it appears but with no tint effect.
How may I achieve this.

Comment: [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

Comment: How to set it for a view ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bottomTab];` when you just added the subview to the view ?

When you add a subview to a view, it has the highest z-Index, so it's going to be in the front anyway.

Second of all, the reason you are not seeing the view, it's because it has a transparent background by default.
The TintColor does not change the background color, but only the tint color of the items you place in a view.

You can simply test this by adding a Button for example in your view:

```
UIView *bottomTab = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT-yVal-bottomBarButtonHeight,SCREEN_WIDTH,75)];
bottomTab.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:bottomTab];

UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
testButton.frame = bottomTab.bounds;
[bottomTab addSubview:testButton];
```

Comment: So how will I get the tint effect

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a glass view?

Comment: I want to achieve a view similar to tab bar or navigation bar which have a tint effect.

Comment: Well you should add a background to your UIView and set a tint color property on the UIKit elements that you will add to your view and not the view itself. Images can also get a tint color, if you use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

I made macros for this purpose:

```
#define removeTint(view) \
if ([((NSNumber *)[view.layer valueForKey:@"__hasTint"]) boolValue]) {\
for (CALayer *layer in [view.layer sublayers]) {\
if ([((NSNumber *)[layer valueForKey:@"__isTintLayer"]) boolValue]) {\
[layer removeFromSuperlayer];\
break;\
}\
}\
}

#define setTint(view, tintColor) \
{\
if ([((NSNumber *)[view.layer valueForKey:@"__hasTint"]) boolValue]) {\
removeTint(view);\
}\
[view.layer setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"__hasTint"];\
CALayer *tintLayer = [CALayer new];\
tintLayer.frame = view.bounds;\
tintLayer.backgroundColor = [tintColor CGColor];\
[tintLayer setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"__isTintLayer"];\
[view.layer addSublayer:tintLayer];\
}
```

---

To use, simply just call:

```
setTint(yourView, yourUIColor);
//Note: include opacity of tint in your UIColor using the alpha channel (RGBA), e.g. [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.25f];
```

When removing the tint simply call:

```
removeTint(yourView);
```